# Web application reference to WCF does not generate proxy classes?

Tags: wcf-client

Currently we have website that must consume a WCF service because our we have x64 web servers and have code dependencies on 32-bit third party assemblies which are not x64 compatible. So WCF service is a wrapper.

When I add the "service reference" there are several file generated but no .cs file. I thought there was suppose to be a reference.cs file containing the proxy stubs for the client code to consume.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Look in the Error and Output windows to see if there were any problems in adding the web reference.

Also, exactly which files were generated? Have you looked at them? There may be clues there.

Comment: got service.xsd, configuration91.svcinfo, configuration.svcinfo, reference.svcmap, service1.xsd, service.wsdl for files. They all contain xml and from my inexpireneced shoes looks to be valid. There are no glaring error messages embedded in them. 

Just re-added it again the errors window shows nothing and the output shows the results of my last compile. So no help here either. 

There is supposed to be a reference.cs file though right?

Comment: Also have tried simplifying my service interface to: int Add(int a, int b); and still get the same results.

Comment: More to add. When I add this service reference to a different project (not a web site) the reference.cs is generated.

Comment: This is the underlying reason not to use Web Site "projects". They're not projects. They behave differently than any other project type in Visual Studio. In this case, your first problem is that you didn't say you were using a web site. In a web site, things that would normally be generated at design time, wait until runtime. That's why no reference.cs was generated.